# One to many relationship of products sold with different time periods

Tags: pivot-table, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot

I need to track the performance of one brand (store brand) versus all other brands. I believe this requires a one to many relationship.
My data set looks like this:

| Date | Type | Product Number | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2020 | Store Brand | 2345 | 500 |
| 01.2020 | Brand | 1111 | 400 |
| 01.2020 | Brand | 2222 | 425 |
| 01.2020 | Brand | 3333 | 450 |
| 02.2020 | Brand | 1111 | 300 |
| 02.2020 | Brand | 2222 | 325 |
| 02.2020 | Brand | 3333 | 350 |
| 03.2020 | Store Brand | 2346 | 600 |

But I need to transform it so that it will look like this:

| Year | Month | Store Brand Product Number | Brand Product Number | Store Brand Sales | Brand Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 2345 | 1111 | 500 | 400 |
| 2020 | 1 | 2345 | 2222 | 500 | 425 |
| 2020 | 1 | 2345 | 3333 | 500 | 450 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2345 | 1111 | 0 | 300 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2345 | 2222 | 0 | 325 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2345 | 3333 | 0 | 350 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2346 | 1112 | 600 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2346 | 2223 | 600 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2346 | 3332 | 600 | 0 |

I have a mapping table that shows which brand products can be compared with a store brand product. Which looks like this:

| Store Brand | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| 2345 | 1111 |
| 2345 | 2222 |
| 2345 | 3333 |
| 2346 | 1112 |
| 2346 | 2223 |
| 2346 | 3332 |

For every time period in the data set all brand products need to be compared to the store brand. If in a certain period no store brand products were sold, then these need to be listed as 0, or as an empty cell. Vice versa, if only store brands were sold in a certain time period, then the comparable brand sales need to be listed as 0, or as an empty cell.

I am using Excel 365, so if possible, please only post answers that I can implement in Excel 365, because I cannot use Power BI Desktop at the moment.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if I need to add additional information.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: @smpa01 I updated the post with a sample data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let
  _mapping = 
    let
      Source = Web.BrowserContents(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349163/one-to-many-relationship-of-products-sold-with-different-time-periods?noredirect=1#comment120797753_68349163"
      ), 
      #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(
        Source, 
        {
          {"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(6) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, 
          {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(6) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}
        }, 
        [RowSelector = "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(6) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]
      ), 
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(
        #"Extracted Table From Html", 
        [PromoteAllScalars = true]
      ), 
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Promoted Headers", 
        {{"Store Brand", Int64.Type}, {"Brand", Int64.Type}}
      )
    in
      #"Changed Type", 
  _fact = 
    let
      Source = Web.BrowserContents(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349163/one-to-many-relationship-of-products-sold-with-different-time-periods?noredirect=1#comment120797753_68349163"
      ), 
      #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(
        Source, 
        {
          {"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, 
          {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, 
          {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, 
          {"Column4", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}
        }, 
        [RowSelector = "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(2) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]
      ), 
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(
        #"Extracted Table From Html", 
        [PromoteAllScalars = true]
      ), 
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Promoted Headers", 
        {
          {"Date", type text}, 
          {"Type", type text}, 
          {"Product Number", Int64.Type}, 
          {"Sales", Int64.Type}
        }
      )
    in
      #"Changed Type", 
  #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_fact, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), 
  #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
    #"Added Index", 
    "Date", 
    Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
    {"month", "year"}
  ), 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    #"Split Column by Delimiter", 
    {{"month", Int64.Type}, {"year", Int64.Type}}
  ), 
  #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(
    #"Changed Type", 
    {"Index", "month", "year", "Type", "Product Number", "Sales"}
  ), 
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    #"Reordered Columns", 
    {"year", "month"}, 
    {
      {
        "ad", 
        each _, 
        type table [
          Index = number, 
          month = nullable number, 
          year = nullable number, 
          Type = nullable text, 
          Product Number = nullable number, 
          Sales = nullable number
        ]
      }
    }
  ), 
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Grouped Rows", 
    "Custom", 
    each 
      let
        x = [ad], 
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(x, {{"Type", Order.Descending}}), 
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
          #"Sorted Rows", 
          "Brand Sales", 
          each if [Type] <> "Store Brand" then [Sales] else null
        ), 
        #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(
          #"Added Custom", 
          "Store Brand Product Number", 
          each if [Type] = "Store Brand" then [Product Number] else null
        ), 
        #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1", {"Store Brand Product Number"}), 
        #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(
          #"Filled Down", 
          "Store Brand Sales", 
          each if [Type] = "Store Brand" then [Sales] else null
        ), 
        #"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom2", {"Store Brand Sales"}), 
        #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down1", each ([Type] = "Brand")), 
        #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(
          #"Filtered Rows", 
          {
            "Index", 
            "year", 
            "month", 
            "Type", 
            "Product Number", 
            "Sales", 
            "Brand Sales", 
            "Store Brand Product Number", 
            "Store Brand Sales"
          }
        ), 
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
          #"Reordered Columns1", 
          {{"Product Number", "Brand Product Number"}}
        ), 
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Type", "Sales"}), 
        #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(
          #"Removed Columns", 
          {
            "Index", 
            "year", 
            "month", 
            "Store Brand Product Number", 
            "Brand Product Number", 
            "Store Brand Sales", 
            "Brand Sales"
          }
        )
      in
        #"Reordered Columns2"
  ), 
  #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Added Custom", 
    "Custom.1", 
    each 
      if Table.IsEmpty([Custom]) = true then
        let
          x = [ad], 
          #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
            x, 
            {"Product Number"}, 
            _mapping, 
            {"Store Brand"}, 
            "_mapping", 
            JoinKind.LeftOuter
          ), 
          #"Expanded _mapping" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
            #"Merged Queries", 
            "_mapping", 
            {"Brand"}, 
            {"Brand"}
          ), 
          #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded _mapping", {"Type"}), 
          #"Reordered Columns3" = Table.ReorderColumns(
            #"Removed Columns1", 
            {"Index", "year", "month", "Product Number", "Sales", "Brand"}
          ), 
          #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(
            #"Reordered Columns3", 
            {
              {"Product Number", "Store Brand Product Number"}, 
              {"Sales", "Store Brand Sales"}, 
              {"Brand", "Brand Product Number"}
            }
          ), 
          #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Brand Sales", each 0), 
          #"Reordered Columns4" = Table.ReorderColumns(
            #"Added Custom3", 
            {
              "Index", 
              "year", 
              "month", 
              "Store Brand Product Number", 
              "Brand Product Number", 
              "Store Brand Sales", 
              "Brand Sales"
            }
          )
        in
          #"Reordered Columns4"
      else
        [Custom]
  ), 
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom.1"}), 
  #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Removed Other Columns", 
    "Custom.1", 
    {
      "Index", 
      "year", 
      "month", 
      "Store Brand Product Number", 
      "Brand Product Number", 
      "Store Brand Sales", 
      "Brand Sales"
    }, 
    {
      "Index", 
      "year", 
      "month", 
      "Store Brand Product Number", 
      "Brand Product Number", 
      "Store Brand Sales", 
      "Brand Sales"
    }
  ), 
  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Custom.1", {{"Index", Order.Ascending}}), 
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each ([Index] <> null)), 
  #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Filtered Rows", {"Store Brand Product Number"}), 
  #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(
    #"Filled Down", 
    null, 
    0, 
    Replacer.ReplaceValue, 
    {"Store Brand Sales"}
  )
in
  #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will look over this and implement it tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Could you please explain what happens in line 99 - 104? #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Grouped Rows", 
    "Custom", 
    each 
      let
        x = [ad],

Comment: Sorry, I realize I added some of my own spacing, and that it is not actually line 99 - 104.

Comment: I was not able to implement your answer because I didn't understand the part I mentioned before. The parts that I did understand though helped me understand how to approach the problem and lead me to finding my own solution. So I still marked your response as the accepted answer because it is probably right and lead me to the solution. Still would appreciate an explanation to the question I asked in the comments. The question is probably really basic, but I am new to Power Query/BI and still learning the fundamentals.